# Changing rectangle margin with code

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to move my Rectangle by pressing down keys, but currently I am getting error that says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Auto,Auto,0,0' is not a valid value for
>   property 'Margin'.

My code is following:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
            double y = Canvas.GetTop(rect);

            if (e.Key == Key.D)
            {
                rect.Margin = new Thickness(x+5, y, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.A)
            {
                rect.Margin = new Thickness(x-5, y, 0, 0);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

Comment: Do you set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on the rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        double x = rect.Margin.Left;
        double y = rect.Margin.Top;
        if (e.Key == Key.D)
        {
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(x+5, y, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            rect.Margin = new Thickness(x-5, y, 0, 0);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, and welcome to SO! Are you able to give a bit more detail? How does this solve the problem?